# Высота блока во весь контейнер

Tags: html, css

Господа, есть такая разметка:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

Хочется сделать нечто вроде этого:

```
<style>
    #container {
        height: 600px;
    }
    #first {
        height: 60px;
    }
    #second {
        height: /*все остальное*/
    }
</style>
```

Так вот, есть ли в CSS способ задать высоту второго блока как разность высот контейнера и первого блока? Хотя бы если высота первого блока фиксированная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/HB5yD/4/)

```
#container {
     height: 600px;
     position: relative;
}
#first {
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
}
#second {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px; /* высота первого блока*/
    bottom: 0; /* прижимаем к низу*/
}
```

Comment: ок, а если нужно поменять местами first и second, а выравниваться все должно относительно контейнера?

Comment: Меняйте спокойно. second уже имеет отступ сверху на высоту первого контейнера, просто в first пропишите ещё top: 0; и всё.

Answer (score 3):

Варианты есть, все зависит от требования к кроссбраузерности, красоте решения и использования js.

Вот [один](http://jsfiddle.net/pcv66/8/) из примеров решения:

```
#container {
   height: 600px;
}

#first {
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#second {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что при таком способе, #first выводится поверх #second, но его атрибут "height" остается 600px?

Comment: Почему же, нет. http://jsfiddle.net/pcv66/9/. Про атрибут не совсем понял.

Comment: Я имею в виду вот что http://jsfiddle.net/ZpHcd/

Comment: Понял, к сожалению всех подробностей рендера данного примера не знаю. Высоту второй элемент будет брать как высоту родителя, но, все-таки, он не под первым блоком и выводится после него. В данном случае с float: left просто не раздувается контейнер, если содержимое не умещается.